# Undefined property: Illuminate\Routing\Router::$app

Tags: laravel, service

I know the `$app` service container is available everywhere in the application. I am registering a class with the Service Container in the routes/web.php like so

```
App::bind('App\Billing\Stripe', function(){
    return new \App\Billing\Stripe(config('services.stripe.secret'));
});
$stripe = App::make('App\Billing\Stripe');
dd($stripe);
```

after dump and die getting result but when using like this

```
App::bind('App\Billing\Stripe', function(){
    return new \App\Billing\Stripe(config('services.stripe.secret'));
});
$stripe = $this->app->make('App\Billing\Stripe');
dd($stripe);
```

getting the following error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Routing\Router::$app
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example would work if you changed it to:

```
App::bind('App\Billing\Stripe', function(){
    return new \App\Billing\Stripe(config('services.stripe.secret'));
});
$stripe = $this->container->make('App\Billing\Stripe');
dd($stripe);
```

That is, in the Router the service container is referenced in `$container`, and not the`$app` property.